# Improving K Means on some data sets

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

Anyone got an idea on how a simple K-means algorithm could be tuned to handle data sets of [this form](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/202010cluster.png).

Comment: *K*-means is not that simple, you need to implement a distance function yourself. You can always make a distance function that groups such points nicely. Furthermore crossvalidated.SE is perhaps a better option than SO.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had a solution in mind. By definition, I have 2 classes (red and blue). What if I increase my K in K-means, lets say to 5 and then I decrease it progressively (one by one) when merging the two clusters that minimize the argmin function? (in this case, the function will increase as K decreases but I will iterate over the pairs and find the pair that makes it increase the least). Hope I'm clear.

Comment: I will think about a distance function that could match this example.
Is cross validation for finding the best form of this distance function?

Comment: You could always use a different clustering algorithm such as DBSCAN which can cluster non-convex data like the example you provided.

Comment: @CommuSoft k-mean is really simple, and should *not* be used with other distance functions, because it minimizes variance, not distances... however, *kernel* k-means is possible (minimizing variance in kernel space) and probably could solve this.

Comment: Yes it works! Thanks all for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most direct way to handle data of that form while still using k-means it to use a kernelized version of k-means. 2 implemtations of it exist in the JSAT library (see here https://github.com/EdwardRaff/JSAT/blob/67fe66db3955da9f4192bb8f7823d2aa6662fc6f/JSAT/src/jsat/clustering/kmeans/ElkanKernelKMeans.java)

As Nicholas said, another option is to create a new feature space on which you run k-means. However this takes some prior knowledge of what kind of data you will be clustering.

After that, you really just need to move to a different algorithm. k-means is a simple algorithm that makes simple assumptions about the world, and when those assumptions are too strongly violated (non linearly separable clusters being one of those assumptions) then you just have to accept that and pick a more appropriate algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution to this problem is to add another dimension to your data set, for which there is a split between the two classes.

Obviously this is not applicable in many cases, but if you have applied some sort of dimensionality reduction to your data, then it may be something worth investigating.